# Resetting index on dictionary of pandas dataframes on first sheet when read in

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I'm currently trying to upload an xlsx file into a dictionary of pandas dataframes to populate with a script. However, in the template file I'm uploading, the first page, 'Test data', doesn't have any headers, just a lot of fields to fill out with data. Currently, when I'm importing it into pandas, this is what my data looks like:

```
template = pd.read_excel('upload_template.xlsx', sheet_name = None)

print (template)

{'Test data':          SI5                  * Test/specimen identifier
0        TS5                               Test standard
1        QR5                              Quality remark
2        CR5                         Completeness remark
```

How do I work it that the first line, SI5 * Test/specimen identifier, is just another row beside the index counter? I only want to do it for this page of the dataframe, all the other pages have headers I wish to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in `header=None` so when the file imports first row is not being treated as the header

```
template = pd.read_excel('upload_template.xlsx', sheet_name = None, header=None)
```

After that, you can set the columns using `df.columns` to set the columns for the dataframe so you can work with